# System.Timers.Timer decaying with each iteration

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Ok so I'm learning C#/.NET and have thus far stuck to winforms, but WPF seemed suitable for this project.

I have a WrapPanel that displays an array of images. Sometimes this array will overspill the confines of the window. I am trying to cycle through the "pages" until all images have been displayed using a timer.

I'll start my code sample at the timer elapsed event, at this point my WrapPanel (wrapPanel1) has already been populated and checked if there is an overflow:

```
public void t2_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        wrapPanel1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate 
        {
            remaining = Convert.ToInt32(imgCount) - (iteration*xDensity);

            label1.Content = iteration;
            label2.Content = remaining;
            label3.Content = imgCount;

            if (remaining <= 1)
            {
                Thickness marginTop = wrapPanel1.Margin;
                marginTop.Top = 0;
                wrapPanel1.Margin = marginTop;
                wrapPanel1.Children.Clear();
                t2.Stop();
                imgLayout();
            }

            else
            {
                Thickness marginTop = wrapPanel1.Margin;
                marginTop.Top = -((prevResY+10) * iteration);
                wrapPanel1.Margin = marginTop;
                iteration++;
            }
        });
    }
```

imgCount is a double that indicates total number of images in the WrapPanel (needs to be a double because of an interaction with another double elsewhere in the code)

xDensity is a user defined int that sets the number of images displayed horizontally.

prevResY is the height of each photo (all the same resolution), I add 10 to account for 5px margin all round which is set when the WrapPanel is populated. By multiplying by the iteration, I always move wrapPanel1 up by 1 row.

imgLayout(); starts the process all over again, as each time I run through all the pages I need to check if there are any new images, and knock any old ones off the end. This is all handled in imgLayout().

I update the labels just so I can keep an eye on it while debugging, they return exactly the values I'd expect.

As you might have gathered from the question title, my problem is that with every iteration of my t2_elapsed, the interval seems to increase. If I set the interval to 10ms just to observe its behaviour, it would appear that the delay increases exponentially. After 30s the delay is about 25s, up from 0.1 observed at first. RAM usage slowly climbs too which suggests to me that some resources aren't being disposed of when the loop restarts, not sure if that is the cause or a separate problem.

Hope someone can help! If I've done something stupid, just tell me, I'm still learning!

Many thanks

----UPDATE----

Ok so I think it's something to do with the

```
wrapPanel1.Children.Clear();
```

line. I removed it and just let it fill up and up and I get no delay, but this obviously isn't the final solution. Wherever I put that line it reproduces the problem.

----UPDATE **2**----

Well I feel rather dumb now. Earlier in the imgLayout() method where the timer is started I was using:

```
t2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 5000);
t2.Tick += new EventHandler(t2_Tick);
t2.Start();
```

I was stupidly declaring the event handler every time the loop restarted. I set it in the Window_Loaded method instead and it's working exactly as one would expect now, just tidied it up a bit and implemented a way of scrolling one whole page at a time instead of just one row.

Comment: How many images are you displaying? Seems like it is unable to clear/dispose of them in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: At the minute for the purpose of testing I have a folder of 9 images, it is set to display 4 at a time. In a real world scenario it could be having to handle up to about 60 at any given time.

Answer (score 4):

It's recommended to use [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) when dealing with repeated operations in WPF. It will automatically execute its code on the dispather thread without needing `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the timer to Dispatcher.Timer, wasn't aware of that one! Memory usage has gone down but the overall problem persists.

Comment: @RMilne: Anyway, glad you found the problem. I was really running out of ideas about what went wrong. Maybe you should post an answer yourself with the solution and mark it as accepted. :)